# qgis-bin.exe stopped working

Tags: qgis, error

Same problems after uninstalling and reinstalling 2.18.3...  Have the crash report, but can't see that I can post it here so anyone can see some answers in it...

Some more information about my problems with QGIS 2.18.3.

- 2.18.3 is the second version I have installed on this computer, the fist was the version before 2.18.3.
- I create a new project with only 2 vector features, no problem with that...
- Then I saved it and try to open the new project again, and get the same problem.
- My QGIS projects is saved in a folder outside QGIS folder
- I have tried to open the project files from explorer with same result

I have a problem with QGIS v. 2.18.3

- I start the program from desktop icon.
- Program start with no problem
- when I double-click on a project I get message "qgis-bin.exe has stopped to work"
- the project I have is very small, just some vector and shape features
- I have reinstalled 2.18.3, but the same thing happens...
- I have a new laptop HP Elitebook, Windows 10.
- I use an extern screen.

What is the problem?

Comment: Impossible to say. Try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Try creating a new project. If you can use QGIS to create a new project then the problem definitely lies with the specific project you are trying to open (or its data) and not QGIS itself.  If it is as small a project as you say, I'd just recreate it.  Searching this site shows many similar questions.

Comment: Try navigating to the project file with the Windows Explorer, and doubleclick on that.

Comment: check what project files are associated with, it may be an old version

Comment: Only some thoughts:
1. Project files are xml formatted files so you can inspect them in a text editor. May be you'll find something weird this way. 
2. Try to open QGIS und then open the project from within QGIS. This may give you more information on that error.
3. Try to rename the .qgis folder in your home directory, sometimes old plugins cause a crash.

Comment: @AndreasMüller the .qgis folder was used by QGIS 1.8 and before, nowadays .qgis2 is used.