# qgis-bin-exe-stopped-working No Shapefiles allowed

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

I'm using Windows 7 and I'm having the problem of QGIS 2.18.16 crashing with any shapefile. Rasters seem to be OK. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling 2.18.15, 2.18.14 and one older version (2.17 or earlier, I can't remember). I turned off all plugins before trying anything. I found earlier advice about changing a registry key, so I used the Windows command line to start regedit and under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER> SOFTWARE> QGIS`I deleted all the QGIS and then did the 2.18.16 install. I also downloaded the OSGeo4W version and tried running QGIS from that.

I haven't tried any other vector formats because I really need to work with shapefiles.  I'm not having any trouble with my desktop, just my laptop. I was using the style editor when the trouble first appeared.

I looked all over at the other posts about this problem, like [qgis-bin.exe stopped working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227538/qgis-bin-exe-stopped-working) and I'm not sure how to provide more information.

Edit: I tried loading a geodatabase with vectors, it worked and I changed a few symbols and saved. Upon exiting I received this same message and now I get this fail when I try opening geodatabases. I also get this fail when I'm loading the new project (with just this simple geodatabase loaded).

Comment: Are you sure you have full write permission in the folder where you have stored the shapefiles?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried many directories.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was cleaning everything out on before reinstalling, but I didn't realize that in windows, the plugins are in a file that starts with a dot:
I had to delete this:
 " C:\Users\myusername\.qgis2 " directory
then restart then reinstall
I also followed a tip elsewhere and deleted the Windows registry Software key (with the registry editor) HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > QGIS
I don't know if that helped.

Comment: should be `C:\users\myusername\.qgis2` which might be hidden on some Windows OS versions.

Comment: Yes! It's one of those odd html things about putting "\" and "." next to each other.